# React gives me the error TypeError: XXX.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and it gives me the error below, which I cannot resolve. I searched in the internet, a lot of people faced the same problem but "map" is a built in function, why does it say that it is not a function?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class UrunlerComponentList extends Component {
    displayName = UrunlerComponentList.name

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { urunler_: [], loading: true };

        fetch('http://localhost:55992/api/search/arama?q=&PageIndex=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ urunler_: data, loading: false });
            });
    }

    static renderUrunlerTable(urunler_) {
        return (
            <table className='table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SKU</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {urunler_.map(urun =>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{urun.SKU}</td>
                            <td>{urun.Name}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : UrunlerComponentList.renderUrunlerTable(this.state.urunler_);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Urunler</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The webapi I am calling returns the value below...

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "RecordCount": 879,
    "products": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "Id": 17034,
            "BrandId": 3,
            "SKU": "7436B003-1082",
            "Name": "xxxxxxxx",
            "InStock": 1,
            "URL": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "Description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Price": 9.90,
            "DiscountRatio": 0.00,
            "TechnicalDetail": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ImageUrl": "7436Bxxxxxx.jpg",
            "Active": true,
            "CreatedDate": "2019-07-20T11:36:35.333",
            "Brand": null,
            "CartDetails": [],
            "OrderDetails": [],
            "ProductCategoryRelations": [],
            "ProductColorRelations": [],
            "ProductFileRelations": [],
            "ProductPropertyRelations": []
        },
```

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint or check the value of ```urunler_``` in the method ```renderUrunlerTable``` and verify whether it is an array or not? If it is an array, please mention the value as well.

Comment: you data is not an array its an object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure the value returned from your fetch call is an `array` and is not `undefined` since you are setting that value to your state.

```
fetch('http://localhost:55992/api/search/arama?q=&PageIndex=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // make sure 'data' is an array
                this.setState({ urunler_: data, loading: false });
            });
```

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ did you downvote everyone trying to help you answer your question?

Comment: @TravisJames I don't think he downvoted,  I guess we made a few people angry by answering a duplicate question:(

Comment: Ahhh I see.  Oh well I suppose haha

Comment: I didnt downvote anyone. Some folks didnt like my question :) Well, if I had resolved my issue with other answers, I wouldnt have created this ticket. Anyway, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. Data itself is an object not an array. You want to assign products I guess.

```
...
.then(({products}) => this.setState({ urunler_: products, loading: false }))
...
```

Comment: How is this downvoted when its saying the same as accepted answer?  Its even nicer because of object deconstruction.

Comment: Mine got downvoted as well even though it says basically the same thing. No idea why...

Answer (score -1):

```
           <tbody>
                {typeof urunler_ !== 'undefined' && urunler_.length > 0 ? 
               (urunler_.map(urun =>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{urun.SKU}</td>
                        <td>{urun.Name}</td>
                    </tr>
                )):(<tr><</tr>)}
            </tbody>
```